# Looping over string elements in Python list and making substitutions

Tags: python, string, list, substitution

I have a list that looks like follows:

```
>>> lst = ['yaktub', 'naktub', 'taktub']
```

I know how to loop over the items in the list. But I want to loop over the characters of each element in the list and make substitutions. I will provide a pseudo code below:

```
for item in lst: 
      for char in lst[item]:
          if lst[item][0] in 'ynt':


                lst[item][0] = char
          elif lst[item][1] in 'a':
                  lst[item][1] = 'a'
          elif lst[item][2] in 'k':
                lst[item][2] = 'f'
       newlst.append(item)
return newlest
```

and so on. I would appreciate it if you could guide me how to do it with indix assignment instead of slicing.

Comment: I dont really understand what your question is ...

Comment: Please explain the logic behind this...

Answer (score 0):

You should use `translate` for that, as in:

```
lst = ['yaktub', 'naktub', 'taktub']
for word in lst:
    print(word.translate(str.maketrans("yntak", "yntaf")))
```

Which outputs:

```
yaftub
naftub
taftub
```

Notice that the first list is the characters you want to replace, and the second are the ones you want to appear in the new strings.

Answer (score 0):

In python a string is simply a list
    'string' == ['s','t','r','i','n','g']
then

```
lst = ['yaktub', 'naktub', 'taktub']
newlst = []
for item in lst: 
      for char in item:
          if char in 'ynt':
              #your operation here
          elif char in 'a':
              #other code here
       newlst.append(item)
return newest
```

I hope this can help you

Answer (score 0):

as I am unsure not the req is but it is probably best to try this

```
def convert_word(word):
    ....your code here and add return statement

map(convert_word,list_to_convert)
```

There you go!

please try to explain requirement better next time